# How to change the url in Connect for Office

Tags: office-connect

I installed the connect for office and after installing i am able to login from excel and word with my Production login credentials, but i don't want to explore the tool with my production org.

Is there a way to change the URL to Sandbox url from excel or word.

I don't find that option to change the url, i see only Log in & Log out options.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to a sandbox using 'Connect for Office' it is necessary to modify the Windows Registry

1. Open Windows Registry Editor:
   For Windows XP:                 Click on Start | Run and type in REGEDIT
   For Windows Vista/7:          Click on Start and type in REGEDIT in the Search box
2. In the Registry Editor navigate to
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Salesforce.com
3. Create a new key and call it 'Word'
4. Highlight 'Word' and on the right hand side, create a STRING called 'Host' and give it the following value:
   https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/12
5. Repeat same if you want to connect to sandbox from Excel but create a key called 'Excel' instead of 'Word'
6. IMPORTANT: In order to connect back to production, it is necessary to remove the Word and Excel keys that were created or change the word 'test' to 'www' for the Host value

See [here](https://na1.salesforce.com/_ui/training/help/pub/UserEdSolution?%20id=50130000000MI1Q&retURL=https://na7.salesforce.com/_ui/training/help/CombinedSearchPage?str=connect%2bfor%2boffice%2bsandbox&ps=1&orgId=00D000000000062) for info